# how to write a function that replaces a categorical variable value in multiple data frames of same structure

Tags: r, function

I am writing a function that will replace a categorical variable `value` here with `NA` when the `value` is equal to 3.

I would like to run this on multiple data frames of different years. All the data frames have the same structure and column names except the variables have a suffix with the specific data year. This is the example data and code

```
df1 <-data.frame(
       year = c(1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997),
       letters97 = LETTERS[1:5],
       id97 = c(4, 1, 8, 1, 9),
       value97 = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3))

df2 <-data.frame(
       year    = c(1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998),
       letters98 = LETTERS[1:5], 
       id98 = c(2, 6, 10, 13, 14), 
       value98 = c(1, 1, 0, 3, 2))

# I tried to change this code into a function: 
df1$value97[df1$value97 == 3] <- NA
    
   # Create function  

recode <- function(year_var, yr){
  year_var$str_replace_all(paste("value", "yr"), " ", "")[year_var$str_replace_all(paste("value", "yr"), " ", "") == 3] <-NA
  table(year_var$str_replace_all(paste("value", yr), " ", ""), useNA = "always")
} 

recode(df1, 97)
recode(df2, 98)
```

I get an error: Error in year_var$str_replace_all(paste("value", "yr"), " ", "")[year_var$str_replace_all(paste("value",  :
target of assignment expands to non-language object

Can you please advise how I would reference the df and variable "value" in the function?

Comment: it sounds like you're trying to rename the value97 and value98 columns, is that correct?

Comment: thanks! I am trying to replace in the columns value97 and value98 where they 3 with 'NA'. The desired output would have would all the values of '3' in value97 and value98 replaced with 'NA". I tried to change this code into a function:  df1$value97[df1$value97 == 3] <- NA

Comment: there is no `it` column, did you mean the `value` column?

Comment: yes where the value columns equal 3

Comment: Mark's answer is the best approach, but if you are trying as a beginner to write a function best to assign you arguments and test individual bits of code. There's a lot of basics you are missing, eg that pasting `paste("value", "yr")` will give you "value yr" as you have quoted by accident. Also you can use `paste0` or set `sep = ""` to remove spaces so you don't need `str_replace_all`. And you cannot access columns from strings with the $ sign you must use `df1[["value97"]]` when you have quotes or are getting column name from string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, storing information in column names is a really bad idea and will lead to buggy code and/or persistent migraines. [See here](http://statseducation.com/Introduction-to-R/modules/tidy%20data/tidy-data/) for more information.

It's much better to pivot the data longer, and have the year as a column. But in this case, you already have a year column, so the years in the column names are redundant.

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

bind_rows(df1 |> pivot_longer(-year, names_to = c(".value", NA), names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)"),
          df2 |> pivot_longer(-year, names_to = c(".value", NA), names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)")) |>
  mutate(value = ifelse(value == 3, NA, value))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
    year letters    id value
   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1997 A           4     0
 2  1997 B           1     0
 3  1997 C           8     1
 4  1997 D           1     2
 5  1997 E           9    NA
 6  1998 A           2     1
 7  1998 B           6     1
 8  1998 C          10     0
 9  1998 D          13    NA
10  1998 E          14     2
```